# Parse class to fetch data from Parse.com

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I wrote a class with methods like fetching, updating, adding and deleting from Parse.com.

I now have a problem with my `getFromParse` method:

```
class ParseModul {

var returnArray = []



func getFromParse(className:String, whereKey:String, equalTo:String) -> NSArray {


    let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: className)
    query.whereKey(whereKey, equalTo: equalTo)


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                var temp = [PFObject]()

                for object in objects {
                    temp.append(object)
                }
                self.returnArray = temp
                print(self.returnArray) // THIS IS THE DATA FROM PARSE
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!)")
        }
    }

    print(self.returnArray.count) // THIS IS 0

    if self.returnArray.count > 0 {

        return self.returnArray

    } else {

        self.returnArray = ["nothing"]

        return self.returnArray
    }

}
}
```

I use it with:

```
let parse:ParseModul = ParseModul()
let mydata = parse.getFromParse("UserProfile", whereKey: "username", equalTo: "Phil")
```

The method always returns "nothing".

Comment: Read about asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning your array before the data is fetched.
The data is fetched in the block may not be returned in the function.

You may get your data in your own block;

```
func getFromParse(className:String, whereKey:String, equalTo:String, completion:(arr:NSArray) -> Void)
 {


    let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: className)
    query.whereKey(whereKey, equalTo: equalTo)


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                var temp = [PFObject]()

                for object in objects {
                    temp.append(object)
                }
                //??self.returnArray = temp
                //??print(self.returnArray) // THIS IS THE DATA FROM PARSE
                completion(temp);
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!)")
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this;

```
let parse:ParseModul = ParseModul()
parse.getFromParse("UserProfile", whereKey: "username", equalTo: "Phil", completion: {
   (arr:NSArray) -> Void in
        self.returnArray = arr
        print(self.returnArray) // THIS IS THE DATA FROM PARSE
        // DO SOMETHING HERE

})
```

Comment: For `completen:(arr:NSArray)` i get. `Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label` and for `completion(temp)` i get `Cannot invoke 'completion' with an argument list of type '([PFObject])'`